# Dax Get latest status of all products at point in time - Using Date Slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem in Power BI that I am trying to solve; the issue is to get the latest status of a product
in a table see dataset below.

| Product | Status | Date | Calculated Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | Status A | 08/04/2023 00:25 | 08/04/2023 00:25 |
| Product A | Status B | 07/04/2023 02:34 | 07/04/2023 02:34 |
| Product A | Status C | 01/04/2023 00:29 | 06/04/2023 00:29 |
| Product A | Status D | 30/03/2023 23:41 | 30/03/2023 23:41 |
| Product A | Status E | 30/03/2023 00:49 | 30/03/2023 00:49 |
| Product B | Status A | 29/03/2023 00:31 | 29/03/2023 00:31 |
| Product B | Status B | 28/03/2023 02:32 | 28/03/2023 02:32 |
| Product B | Status C | 26/03/2023 23:42 | 31/03/2023 23:42 |
| Product C | Status D | 26/03/2023 00:44 | 26/03/2023 00:44 |

Calculated Date is Date plus 5days Where Status = "Status C"  this is a calculated column in the dataset.

The problem is that I would like to filter the dataset using a Slicer on the Calculated date column
to get the latest for each product depending on slicer date.

**For example : - slicer date is 06/04/2023 00:00**

**Result should be**

| Product | Status | Date | Calculated Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | Status C | 01/04/2023 00:29 | 06/04/2023 00:29 |
| Product B | Status C | 26/03/2023 23:42 | 31/03/2023 23:42 |
| Product C | Status D | 26/03/2023 00:44 | 26/03/2023 00:44 |

We would like to represent this data as graphs and charts.

**Follow-up issue**
See image below I can't represent "table with filter" in a visual which I'd like to represent as a count of product by Status.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17dLk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slicer needs to be from a separate table to your data table. Do you have a Date table already? If so, you can use that for your slicer.

You can then use the following measure:

```
Latest Product Count = 
  var slicerDate = DATE(2023, 4, 6) // change to MAX('SlicerDateTable[Date])
  var latest =
    GENERATE(
      SELECTCOLUMNS(DISTINCT('Product'[Product]), "P", [Product]),
      TOPN(1, FILTER(ALL('Product'), 'Product'[Product] = [P] && 'Product'[Calculated Date] <= slicerDate), [Calculated Date], DESC)
    )
  return COUNTROWS(FILTER(latest, [Product] IN VALUES('Product'[Product]) && [Status] IN VALUES('Product'[Status])))
```

Then add this new measure as a visual filter and set it to `is not blank`. **Or** use this measure directly in charts for Values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sam, this works to some extent but when I don't use 'Product'[Calculated Date] in my visual it will not calculate properly; as in the count Product etc. is there any way around this ?

Comment: Can you share a screengrab or share an example of it not working? I am unable to reproduce the issue on this end. Which visual are you using?

Comment: Hi Sam I've updated the query with an image of the example data; the main problem is that I can't represent "table with filter" in a visual which I'd like to represent as a count of products by status.

Comment: Understood - try the updated answer above. You can use this measure as a Visual filter as before, **or** as a count to be used in chart values or axis.

Comment: Sam thank you for the update this now works as outlined appreciate your hep